# How can i use multithreading to handle a list in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, transactions

I  have a big Table , about 1 million records , and it's increasing .....

Now i want retrieve 1K records to a list (List) and do something with it and save results to 3 table (use transaction ) , when these 1k records are handled , how can i know and retrieve again ....

i used Ado.net entity framework as data access module .

I want to use MultiThreading  , but i am not very familiar with it.
how can i get this done .

could you give me some sample code  or Pseudocode  ?

Comment: Have you even tried googling for the answer? StackOverflow is for asking concrete questions and getting concrete answers.

Comment: You have a big chunk of data in one table, and need to push it into 3 tables... why would you take that over the network? just do it via TSQL at the server...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on .NET 4.0 I would recommend you using the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) to perform any sort of parallel operations.

Here's an example of how you could use it in your scenario:

```
IEnumerable<Entity> entities;
int rangeStartIndex = 0;
int rangeLength = 1000;

do
{
    entities = dataContext.Entities
        .Skip(rangeStartIndex)
        .Take(rangeLength);

    Parallel.ForEach(
        entities,
        item =>
        {
            // Process a single entity in the list
        });

    using (var tran = new TransactionScope())
    {
        // Persist the entities in the database
        tran.Complete();
    }

    rangeStartIndex += rangeLength;

} while (entities.Any());
```

Here we are **processing the list of entities in a parallel fashion** using the [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001.aspx) method, without having to worry about managing threads.

**Related resources:**

- [Parallel Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd987541.aspx)
- [TPL and Traditional .NET Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423.aspx)

Comment: can i use put " using (var tran = new TransactionScope())
    {
        // Persist the entities in the database
        tran.Complete();
    } " in item=>{.....}

Comment: @user655621 You certainly could. However you should be aware that the code passed as delegate in the `Parallel.ForEach` method will be executed **once for each element of the source collection**. With this in mind, it's probably not the place where you would start a transaction.

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio it's 2014, and I have a doubt in this `Parallel.ForEach(entities,item => {
            // Process a single entity in the list });` won't we need to maintain `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Concurrent Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx). In this particular case you can try [ConcurrentBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx).

Comment: I'm not sure that really answers the question; making code multi-threaded is a bit more involved than just having a thread-safe collection to put the data in...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using entity framework, why not declare methods in your repository layer like:

```
public IEnumerable<Order> GetOrders(int skip, int take)
{
    return _context.Orders.Skip(skip).Take(take).AsEnumerable();
}

public IEnumerable<Order> GetOrders(Expression<Func<Order, bool>> predicate, int skip, int take)
{
    return _context.Orders.Where(predicate).Skip(skip).Take(take).AsEnumerable();
}
```

You can then call the required method in a loop to pull back blocks of data and since the IQueryable isn't executed until .AsEnumerable() is called, you'll get an efficient paging mechanism.

Obivously this solution isn't multi-threaded but you could use it as the basis of your threaded looping construct as long as you ensure that your counter variables are marked as volatile.